# How to access another array and loop through it in Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So in my firebase app, I want to access an array whenever the data source is updated.

This part of app works well. The variables are assigned successfully.

```
exports.sendUsersNotification = functions.database.ref('/Groups/{groupId}/messageList/{messageId}/')
.onWrite(event => {
  const original = event.data.val();
  let userId = original['userId']
  let groupId = event.params.groupId;
  let messageId = event.params.messageId;

  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: 'Messenger',
      body: 'You have a new message'
    }
  };



});
```

The array I want to access and loop through is in 'Groups/{groupId}/listeners'.

How can I access it?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions [database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) will only give you the data at the location in the database that matches the pattern you gave in `functions.database.ref()`.  You can use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to query the database at other locations, or you can use `event.data.ref.root` to build a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference) to other locations, and use [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) to perform the query.  There are a lot of examples of this in [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) and [samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/).

Comment: @BobSnyder That's right, I made a mistake, will correct.  No one should be using on() in a function, really.